# Is it possible to fix pixels of a picture in jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am dealing with a report application that outputs some charts in picture formats like JPEG, PNG etc.

What I want to do is to fix 100px from top and 100px from left so that while the scrollable data is shown in the center, first column(name bar) and the top header(date) stays fixed. It is possible to do it with a HTML table structure but since I am working with ONE .jpeg file it does not work for me. Shortly, I need to divide one picture into pieces with CSS or jQuery.

[EXAMPLE](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html)

This is what I am trying to do exactly. But I need to do it with a .jpeg file as I mentioned. I have to work with one stable image, means I can't request to divide the pictures into 3 pieces like; Header, First Column, Data.

Comment: "I searched over the web and could not find even just one useful code." Well, you could... *gasp*... write it yourself! Then when you run into problems, ask here.

Comment: What @Doorknob meant to say is: here on StackOverflow, we like to see specific code that you've tried already. As it is, your problem is difficult to answer since we're not exactly clear what your problem is.

Comment: I did not mean the whole code. Of course I will write the code myself. But without knowing the way to do this it is not possible for me to start. Well I could really use some help instead of pre-judging comments..

Comment: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html

This is what I am trying to do exactly. But I need to do it with a .jpeg file as I mentioned. I have to work with one stable image, means I can't request to divide the pictures into 3 pieces like;
Header,
First Column,
Data.

Comment: You could "split" the image by getting creative with 3 seperate divs, using the same background image, and the css background-position property to only show what you want.

Comment: Hint: you *can* divide the picture into three if you use three copies of the picture.

Comment: Thank you all guys I will try to emulate it with css. If i do then post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this question deserves all the downvoting.

As I understand it, the question is asking if it is possible to hold constant in a browser a part of an image and scroll the rest.

I think that the answer is no, but you can emulate it using two - sorry, three - copies of the image, using the CSS 'clip' property to extract appropriate parts of the images and other CSS to handle the scrolling. I don't have time to provide a worked example.

Comment: Thanks for your help and also for your kindness, I will make a research on emulating it using CSS clip. Thank you for your help again.